# How to edit MANIFEST file to run JAR as administrator? (Windows)

Tags: java

I need to make one operation in my Java app, that requires Administrator privileges (on Windows 7/8).

From all I've read there are just three options:

1) Run a cmd as admin, and there do `java -jar myapp.jar` (or make a .bat file to do same thing)

2) Make a launcher JAR that will run my main JAR through `Elevate.exe` to give it admin access.

3) Edit MANIFEST.MF file to tell Windows that my app needs admin access.

First two approaches sound like a hack to me.
I like the idea to edit `MANIFEST.mf` file, BUT it looks like it only works when I convert my JAR to EXE (at least from what I found).

Anyway, my question is - what's the BEST way to run JAVA GUI program with Administrator privileges? And if you think best way is to edit MANIFEST file - then HOW to do it in NetBeans? (assuming that all I have now is a program in NetBeans, and it's compiled JAR).

Comment: I'm currently trying to figure out the same thing. Right now I'm converting the jar to an exe with an appropriately edited manifest file.

Comment: Can you please send some examples how you are doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently using [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) to turn my jar into an exe. This tool allows you an option to include a manifest file, so I created a manifest file per [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx).

```
<requestedExecutionLevel
level="asInvoker|highestAvailable|requireAdministrator"
uiAccess="true|false"/>
```

Comment: I started reading about Java Web Start (which I need anyway to update the app). There's a piece of code you can add to it, to request full access to the machine. That's what I want to try. Check out the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/development.html) if you want.

Comment: @FRANKLIN i have the jar file and I have created the .exe from it through the tool specified by you,But i am not able to understand that where and how to modify my present manifest file.I created my present jar file through netbeans by cleaning and building.Now for running it as an administrator , i am still in dark.